# std::unique_ptr and pointer-to-pointer

Tags: com, c++11

I've been using std::unique_ptr to store some COM resources, and provided a custom deleter function. However, many of the COM functions want pointer-to-pointer. Right now, I'm using the implementation detail of _Myptr, in my compiler. Is it going to break unique_ptr to be accessing this data member directly, or should I store a gajillion temporary pointers to construct unique_ptr rvalues from?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but anyway, are you aware that unique_ptr has a member function named get(), which returns the underlying pointer ?

Comment: @Thomas: An rvalue, which I obviously can't take the address of. You can't get a `T**` from a `unique_ptr<T>`.

Comment: Why don't you use `ATL::CComPtr` or `_com_ptr_t`?

Comment: @sharptooth: As far as I know, they offer shared_ptr functionality, and I'm after unique_ptr functionality.

Comment: @DeadMG: Okay, but what will you do if you pass the encapsulated pointer into some COM object and that object stores it and does an `AddRef()` and your `unique_ptr` deletes the object? The pointer will become dangling, won't it?

Comment: @sharptooth: You can't `delete` a COM object anyway, you need a custom destructor which calls `Release()`.

Comment: @DeadMG: Technically you can once certain requirements are met, but that's usually the wrong thing to do. My point is anything like `uniqie_ptr` conflicts with reference-counting, so you should instead use `CComPtr` or `_com_ptr_t`.

Comment: @sharptooth: My application only holds one reference. There's no need to go reference counting for my one reference.

Comment: @DeadMG: No problem, but some other COM object you're not aware of could have got hold on the object and wish to share ownership. You just can't combine "I think I'm the only one who holds a pointer" with COM objects since they are all designed to support reference counting.

Comment: My point is even if you don't need reference counting you'll have to use it.

Comment: Btw which do you manage - COM objects or some other stuff like BSTRs?

Comment: @sharptooth: You're misreading me. *I* only hold one reference. The other references are still all counted. And it's just COM objects- working with DirectX.

Comment: I see. What direct negative consequences do you expect if you use `CComPtr` or anything similar?

Comment: @sharptooth: I don't have any need of those libraries or that functionality, so why would I?

Comment: Yes, I fully understand that this feels inelegant and not completely appropriate for your usecase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

COM objects are reference-countable by their nature, so you shouldn't use anything except reference-counting smart pointers like `ATL::CComPtr` or `_com_ptr_t` even if it seems inappropriate for your usecase (I fully understand your concerns, I just think you assign too much weight to them). Both classes are designed to be used in all valid scenarios that arise when COM objects are used, including obtaining the pointer-to-pointer. Yes, that's a bit too much functionality, but if you don't expect any specific negative consequences you can't tolerate you should just use those classes - they are designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: This.  The COM objects are reference counted anyway, so whether you like it or not, anything you do will be a redundant wrapper on top of that.  boost::unique_ptr is not designed for this so any attempt to shoe-horn it in will add needless complexity and chance for error.  CComPtr has no overhead.  Just use that.

Answer (score 4):

I've had to tackle the same problem not too long ago, and I came up with two different solutions:

The first was a simple wrapper that encapsulated a 'writeable' pointer and could be `std::move`d into my smart pointer. This is just a little more convenient that using the temp pointers you are mentioning, since you cannot define the type directly at the call-site.

Therefore, I didn't stick with that. So what I did was a `Retrieve` helper-function that would get the COM function and return my smart-pointer (and do all the temporary pointer stuff internally). Now this trivially works with free-functions that only have a single `T**` parameter. If you want to use this on something more complex, you can just pass in the call via `std::bind` and only leave the pointer-to-be-returned free.

I know that this is not directly what you're asking, but I think it's a neat solution to the problem you're having.

As a side note, I'd prefer boost's intrusive_ptr instead of std::unique_ptr, but that's a matter of taste, as always.

**Edit:** Here's some sample code that's transferred from my version using boost::intrusive_ptr (so it might not work out-of-the box with unique_ptr)

```
template <class T, class PtrType, class PtrDel>
HRESULT retrieve(T func, std::unique_ptr<PtrType, PtrDel>& ptr)
{
  ElementType* raw_ptr=nullptr;

  HRESULT result = func(&raw_ptr);
  ptr.reset(raw_ptr);

  return result;
}
```

For example, it can be used like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<IFileDialog, ComDeleter> FileDialog;
/*...*/
using std::bind;
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::unique_ptr<IShellItem, ComDeleter> ShellItem;
HRESULT status = retrieve(bind(&IFileDialog::GetResult, FileDialog, _1), ShellItem);
```

For bonus points, you can even let `retrieve` return the unique_ptr instead of taking it by reference. The functor that `bind` generates should have signature typedefs to derive the pointer type. You can then throw an exception if you get a bad `HRESULT`.

Answer (score 1):

C++0x smart pointers have a portable way to get at the raw pointer container .get() or release it entirely with .release().  You could also always use &(*ptr) but that is less idiomatic.

If you want to use smart pointers to manage the lifetime of an object, but still need raw pointers to use a library which doesn't support smart pointers (including standard c library) you can use those functions to most conveniently get at the raw pointers.

Remember, you still need to keep the smart pointer around for the duration you want the object to live (so be aware of its lifetime).

Something like:

```
call_com_function( &my_uniq_ptr.get() ); // will work fine
return &my_localscope_uniq_ptr.get();    // will not
return &my_member_uniq_ptr.get();        // might, if *this will be around for the duration, etc..
```

Note: this is just a general answer to your question.  How to best use COM is a separate issue and sharptooth may very well be correct.

Comment: You've completely misread the question. I need a pointer to the *internal* pointer in `unique_ptr`, not just the value.

Comment: unique_ptr doesn't provide a way to directly access the internal pointer because it would be dramatically unsafe to do so.  The point of smart pointers is to be safe.

Answer (score -1):

Use a helper function like this.

```
template< class T >
T*& getPointerRef ( std::unique_ptr<T> & ptr )
{
    struct Twin : public std::unique_ptr<T>::_Mybase {};
    Twin * twin = (Twin*)( &ptr );
    return twin->_Myptr;
}
```

check the implementation

```
int wmain ( int argc, wchar_t argv[] )
{   
    std::unique_ptr<char> charPtr ( new char[25] );
    delete getPointerRef(charPtr);
    getPointerRef(charPtr) = 0;

    return charPtr.get() != 0;
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that you `delete` what you `new[]`.